# Has anyone figured out how to use activity end time on a webform instead of duration?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, civicase, activities

I've installed civi for many organizations and every single one of the groups would prefer to select an end time for activities instead of duration.
Ideally I'd like for them to enter the activity's end time on the webform that collects the activity and automatically calculate the duration.

Has anyone successfully implemented this?

Comment: That would be difficult - how far do you get with webform calculator module?

Comment: If not w/ webform_calculator (time math is probably not supported) we could add this as a feature in webform_civicrm module itself. Let me know if your orgs are interested in becoming a webform_civicrm sponsor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I tried a bunch of different math calculations within webform but couldn't get anything to work in a large part because of how civi stores date info.